# setAppCachePath and setAppCacheEnabled these are not work in android 33

Tags: java, android, android-webview

```
webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath("/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/cache");
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
```

```
error: cannot find symbol
        webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath("/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/cache");
                             ^
  symbol:   method setAppCachePath(String)
  location: class WebSettings
```

What is an alternative for these lines?

```
private void enableHTML5AppCache() {
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath("/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/cache");
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
}
```

Can anyone provide me a solution of these errors?

Comment: I am also getting error on exact ` webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath()` line, If you have got solution then please share it

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. I need to set the cache path.

Answer (score 1):

use reflection to avoid compile failure when you set compileSdk>=33

```
/**
 * handle sdk>=33(android 13) WebSettings remove setAppCachePath
 *
 * @author androidmalin
 *
 * @param webSettings  WebSettings
 * @param appCachePath appCachePath
 */
public static void handleWebSettings_setAppCachePath(WebSettings webSettings, String appCachePath) {
    if (webSettings == null) return;
    if (appCachePath == null || appCachePath.isEmpty()) return;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 33) return;
    // sdk>=33(android 13) remove setAppCachePath Method
    try {
        // public abstract void setAppCachePath(String appCachePath);
        Class<?> webSettingsClazz = Class.forName("android.webkit.WebSettings");
        //noinspection JavaReflectionMemberAccess
        Method setAppCachePathMethod = webSettingsClazz.getDeclaredMethod("setAppCachePath", String.class);
        setAppCachePathMethod.setAccessible(true);
        setAppCachePathMethod.invoke(webSettings, appCachePath);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        //ignore
    }
}
```